How to count how many 1's there are within each row over a set number of columns depending on number of missing/NA's present in each row in R?
I want to create a new column "X11" that sums up all the 1's conditionally based on how  many NA's there are within a select number of columns. In this case, I am looking at 4 variables: X1, X2, X3, and X4.
Ex: if there is 1 NA, then I want to look at the remaining 3 variables that have values and count how many 1's there are. If there are 2 NA's, then I want to look at the remaining 2 variables and count how many 1's there are. If I have 3 NA's, then I want to look at the remaining 1 variable and determine if it is a 1. If I have all 4 NA's, then this would give me 0.
I have this data:
df <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:2, 10, rep=TRUE)))
df <- replace(df, df == 0, NA)

My data frame looks like this:
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1   1  1 NA  1 NA NA NA  1  1   2
2  NA  1  1 NA  2 NA  2  2 NA   1
3   1 NA  1  1 NA NA  1  2 NA   1
4   2  2  2  1  1  2  1 NA  2   2
5  NA  2 NA  2 NA  2  1 NA  1   1
6   2  2  1  1  2 NA  1  2  1   1
7   1  2 NA NA  2  1  1 NA NA   1
8   2  2 NA NA  1 NA NA  2 NA   1
9   1 NA  1  2  2  1  2 NA NA   1
10 NA  2  1 NA NA NA NA  2  2  NA

I want my output to look like this:
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11
1   1  1 NA  1 NA NA NA  1  1   2   3
2  NA  1  1 NA  2 NA  2  2 NA   1   2
3   1 NA  1  1 NA NA  1  2 NA   1   3
4   2  2  2  1  1  2  1 NA  2   2   1
5  NA  2 NA  2 NA  2  1 NA  1   1   0
6   2  2  1  1  2 NA  1  2  1   1   2
7   1  2 NA NA  2  1  1 NA NA   1   1
8   2  2 NA NA  1 NA NA  2 NA   1   0
9   1 NA  1  2  2  1  2 NA NA   1   2
10 NA  2  1 NA NA NA NA  2  2  NA   1

Here is an example of my current code:
vars <- c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4")
df <- df %>%
   mutate(missing_vars = rowSums(across(vars, ~is.na(.))),
          nonmissing_vars = 7-vars)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(zero_na = case_when(missing_vars == 0 & (X1 == 2 & X2 == 2 & X3 == 2 & X4 == 2) ~ 1,
                                (missing_vars == 0 & (X1 == 1 & X2 == 2 & X3 == 2 & X4 == 2) |
                                   (X1 == 2 & X2 == 1 & X3 == 2 & X4 == 2) |
                                   (X1 == 2 & X2 == 2 & X3 == 1 & X4 == 2) |
                                   (X1 == 2 & X2 == 2 & X3 == 2 & X4 == 1)) ~ 2,
                                (missing_vars == 0 & (X1 == 1 & X2 == 1 & X3 == 2 & X4 == 2) |
                                   (X1 == 1 & X2 == 2 & X3 == 1 & X4 == 2) |
                                   (X1 == 1 & X2 == 2 & X3 == 2 & X4 == 1) |
                                   (X1 == 2 & X2 == 1 & X3 == 1 & X4 == 2) |
                                   (X1 == 2 & X2 == 2 & X3 == 1 & X4 == 1) |
                                   (X1 == 2 & X2 == 1 & X3 == 2 & X4 == 1)) ~ 3,
                                (missing_vars == 0 & (X1 == 1 & X2 == 1 & X3 == 1 & X4 == 2) |
                                   (X1 == 1 & X2 == 1 & X3 == 2 & X4 == 1) |
                                   (X1 == 1 & X2 == 2 & X3 == 1 & X4 == 1) |
                                   (X1 == 2 & X2 == 1 & X3 == 1 & X4 == 1)) ~ 4,
                                missing_vars == 0 & (X1 == 1 & X2 == 1 & X3 == 1 & X4 == 1) ~ 5))

brfss <- brfss %>%
  mutate(one_na = case_when(missing_vars == 1 & (is.na(X1) & X2 == 2 & X3 == 2 & X4 == 2) ~ 1,
                                       missing_vars == 1 & (X1 == 2 & is.na(X2) & X3 == 2 & X4 == 2) ~ 1,
                                       missing_vars == 1 & (X1 == 2 & X2 == 2 & is.na(X3) & X4 == 2) ~ 1,
                                       missing_vars == 1 & (X1 == 2 & X2 == 2 & X3 == 2 & is.na(X4)) ~ 1,
                                       missing_vars == 1 & (is.na(X1) & X2 == 1 & X3 == 2 & X4 == 2) ~ 2,
                                       missing_vars == 1 & (X1 == 1 & is.na(X2) & X3 == 2 & X4 == 2) ~ 2,
                                       missing_vars == 1 & (X1 == 1 & X2 == 2 & is.na(X3) & X4 == 2) ~ 2,
                                       missing_vars == 1 & (X1 == 1 & X2 == 2 & X3 == 2 & is.na(X4)) ~ 2,
                                       missing_vars == 1 & (is.na(X1) & X2 == 2 & X3 == 1 & X4 == 2) ~ 2,
                                       missing_vars == 1 & (X1 == 2 & is.na(X2) & X3 == 1 & X4 == 2) ~ 2,
                                       missing_vars == 1 & (X1 == 2 & X2 == 1 & is.na(X3) & X4 == 2) ~ 2,
                                       missing_vars == 1 & (X1 == 2 & X2 == 1 & X3 == 2 & is.na(X4)) ~ 2,
                                       missing_vars == 1 & (is.na(X1) & X2 == 2 & X3 == 2 & X4 == 1) ~ 2,
                                       missing_vars == 1 & (X1 == 2 & is.na(X2) & X3 == 2 & X4 == 1) ~ 2,
                                       missing_vars == 1 & (X1 == 2 & X2 == 2 & is.na(X3) & X4 == 1) ~ 2,
                                       missing_vars == 1 & (X1 == 2 & X2 == 2 & X3 == 1 & is.na(X4)) ~ 2,
                                       missing_vars == 1 & (is.na(X1) & X2 == 1 & X3 == 1 & X4 == 2) ~ 3,
                                       missing_vars == 1 & (X1 == 1 & is.na(X2) & X3 == 1 & X4 == 2) ~ 3,
                                       missing_vars == 1 & (X1 == 1 & X2 == 1 & is.na(X3) & X4 == 2) ~ 3,
                                       missing_vars == 1 & (X1 == 1 & X2 == 1 & X3 == 2 & is.na(X4)) ~ 3,
                                       missing_vars == 1 & (is.na(X1) & X2 == 2 & X3 == 1 & X4 == 1) ~ 3,
                                       missing_vars == 1 & (X1 == 2 & is.na(X2) & X3 == 1 & X4 == 1) ~ 3,
                                       missing_vars == 1 & (X1 == 2 & X2 == 1 & is.na(X3) & X4 == 1) ~ 3,
                                       missing_vars == 1 & (X1 == 2 & X2 == 1 & X3 == 1 & is.na(X4)) ~ 3,
                                       missing_vars == 1 & (is.na(X1) & X2 == 1 & X3 == 2 & X4 == 1) ~ 3,
                                       missing_vars == 1 & (X1 == 1 & is.na(X2) & X3 == 2 & X4 == 1) ~ 3,
                                       missing_vars == 1 & (X1 == 1 & X2 == 2 & is.na(X3) & X4 == 1) ~ 3,
                                       missing_vars == 1 & (X1 == 1 & X2 == 2 & X3 == 1 & is.na(X4)) ~ 3,
                                       missing_vars == 1 & (is.na(X1) & X2 == 1 & X3 == 1 & X4 == 1) ~ 4,
                                       missing_vars == 1 & (X1 == 1 & is.na(X2) & X3 == 1 & X4 == 1) ~ 4,
                                       missing_vars == 1 & (X1 == 1 & X2 == 1 & is.na(X3) & X4 == 1) ~ 4,
                                       missing_vars == 1 & (X1 == 1 & X2 == 1 & X3 == 1 & is.na(X4)) ~ 4))

I repeat this with each combination for 2 NA's, 3 NA's and then 4 NA's and then sum "zero_na", "one_na", etc. to get the final count of the value under X11.
However, I currently have about 300,000 observations and need to do this across 7 different variables with varying amounts of NA's, 1's and 2's. This will be a ridiculous amount of combinations I will have to write and I just wanted to know if there is a more efficient way of writing this code?
Thank you so much in advance!

Maybe another way to frame it is, "if there is 1 NA, then how many 1's are there across the remaining selected columns; if there are 2 NA's, then how many 2's are there across the remaining selected columns; if there are 3 NA's, then how many 1's are there across the remaining selected columns?"

Try this:
df["X11"] = apply(df[,c(1:4)],1,\(s) sum(s==1,na.rm=T))

You can achieve the same result using rowwise() and c_across() if you are partial to a dplyr solution
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(x11 = sum(c_across(X1:X4)==1, na.rm=T))

Output:
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11
1   1  1 NA  1 NA NA NA  1  1   2   3
2  NA  1  1 NA  2 NA  2  2 NA   1   2
3   1 NA  1  1 NA NA  1  2 NA   1   3
4   2  2  2  1  1  2  1 NA  2   2   1
5  NA  2 NA  2 NA  2  1 NA  1   1   0
6   2  2  1  1  2 NA  1  2  1   1   2
7   1  2 NA NA  2  1  1 NA NA   1   1
8   2  2 NA NA  1 NA NA  2 NA   1   0
9   1 NA  1  2  2  1  2 NA NA   1   2
10 NA  2  1 NA NA NA NA  2  2  NA   1


Thank you! I ended up using: df <- df %>%
mutate(X11 = rowSums(across(X1:X4)==1, na.rm=T)) because rowwise() and c_across() was taking a bit long. I appreciate your help!!!

Simply use rowSums():
  df$X11 = rowSums(df[1L:4L] == 1L, na.rm = TRUE)
  df
#>    X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11
#> 1   1  1 NA  1 NA NA NA  1  1   2   3
#> 2  NA  1  1 NA  2 NA  2  2 NA   1   2
#> 3   1 NA  1  1 NA NA  1  2 NA   1   3
#> 4   2  2  2  1  1  2  1 NA  2   2   1
#> 5  NA  2 NA  2 NA  2  1 NA  1   1   0
#> 6   2  2  1  1  2 NA  1  2  1   1   2
#> 7   1  2 NA NA  2  1  1 NA NA   1   1
#> 8   2  2 NA NA  1 NA NA  2 NA   1   0
#> 9   1 NA  1  2  2  1  2 NA NA   1   2
#> 10 NA  2  1 NA NA NA NA  2  2  NA   1

and specify na.rm = TRUE.

Note
Data provided
  df = read.table(text = "   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1   1  1 NA  1 NA NA NA  1  1   2
2  NA  1  1 NA  2 NA  2  2 NA   1
3   1 NA  1  1 NA NA  1  2 NA   1
4   2  2  2  1  1  2  1 NA  2   2
5  NA  2 NA  2 NA  2  1 NA  1   1
6   2  2  1  1  2 NA  1  2  1   1
7   1  2 NA NA  2  1  1 NA NA   1
8   2  2 NA NA  1 NA NA  2 NA   1
9   1 NA  1  2  2  1  2 NA NA   1
10 NA  2  1 NA NA NA NA  2  2  NA", header = TRUE)


Here is a trick with ^ + is.na + rowSums
> df$X11 <- rowSums(!is.na(df[1:4]^NA))

> df
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11
1   1  1 NA  1 NA NA NA  1  1   2   3
2  NA  1  1 NA  2 NA  2  2 NA   1   2
3   1 NA  1  1 NA NA  1  2 NA   1   3
4   2  2  2  1  1  2  1 NA  2   2   1
5  NA  2 NA  2 NA  2  1 NA  1   1   0
6   2  2  1  1  2 NA  1  2  1   1   2
7   1  2 NA NA  2  1  1 NA NA   1   1
8   2  2 NA NA  1 NA NA  2 NA   1   0
9   1 NA  1  2  2  1  2 NA NA   1   2
10 NA  2  1 NA NA NA NA  2  2  NA   1


This worked. Thank you!!
